# getElementById returning null on Android WebView (only with local html)

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, pdf.js

I'm currently writing a simple Android App due to testing purpose. In it there's a WebView-Element in which a html-File (with javascript (Mozilla PDFJS))  from asset folder should be displayed. From Fragment-Code:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", content, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

with content already containing the folowing html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var mypdf = null;
var currentPage = 1;
PDFJS.workerSrc = 'file:///android_asset/pdf.worker.jas';

PDFJS.getDocument('file:///android_asset/pdf.pdf').then(function(pdf) {
    mypdf = pdf;
    renderPage(currentPage);
});

function renderPage(pageNumber) {
    mypdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function(page) {
        var scale = 1;
        var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

        var canvas = document.getElementById('viewer');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.height = viewport.height-40;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;

        var renderContext = {
            canvasContext: context,
            viewport: viewport
        };
        page.render(renderContext);
    });

}
</script>
....
<body>
<h1>Header</h1>
<canvas id="viewer"></canvas>
</body>
```

In logcat I receive the following chromium console output and due to that rendering of the requestet pdf-page does not happen (still, the header is displayed normally)

> I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(22)] "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null", source: file:///android_asset/ (22)

Line 22 refering to

> var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

When I load the exact same file from a remote server (replacing the file:///-links) via webView.loadUrl("http://www.dennissch.de/pdftest/"); everything works fine.
So how come that document.getElementById seems not to work on the local file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That might be due to the fact that your script tag is declared above the canvas. try to put your tag below the viewer, and it should work

```
<body>
<h1>Header</h1>
<canvas id="viewer"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
var mypdf = null;
var currentPage = 1;
PDFJS.workerSrc = 'file:///android_asset/pdf.worker.jas';

PDFJS.getDocument('file:///android_asset/pdf.pdf').then(function(pdf) {
    mypdf = pdf;
    renderPage(currentPage);
});

function renderPage(pageNumber) {
    mypdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function(page) {
        var scale = 1;
        var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

        var canvas = document.getElementById('viewer');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.height = viewport.height-40;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;

        var renderContext = {
            canvasContext: context,
            viewport: viewport
        };
        page.render(renderContext);
    });

}
</script>
</body>
```

Or at least put the call to renderPage below the viewer in an other script tag

Comment: I should do that thought it's working on the remote side, that lead me to another error: the way I builded up the content-String it wasn't always complete but cut after 1024 characters.
Nevertheless I put my JS in a `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { ... }`

Comment: What do you mean by content string?

Comment: In the last line of my Fragment-Code I refered to the variable `content` (which holds the HTML-code) and in some conditions it could happen, that the variable didn't hold all of the code.